# Vim how to reset the screen before editing?

Tags: vim

On Linux, if I do a command with long output, for example `dmesg` and then
edit a file with vim the screen is like after `reset` command.

On HP-UX, if I do a command with long output, for example `dmesg` and then
edit a file with vim the screen is still filled with output of dmesg.

How to reset screen before edit with vim?

Let see,on linux,screen is occupied by vim,is that i want

[image]

On hpux,you will see part of dmesg output on screen

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what "reset screen before edit" means. Do you want to see the dmesg output again after vi exits, or ... ?

Comment: Sorry for unclear message,i will put two images for clear

Comment: it looks a little bit like you've scrolled the HPUX window up a bit?

Comment: Probably,but on linux i can scroll or run vim in console with 10000 lines of output,it reset the screen,very nice,how to do same thing on hpux?is 100% a vim settings.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367068/clear-a-terminal-screen-for-real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshots in the question do not show `dtterm` (some people are confused by the ability to set the `TERM` environment variable to `dtterm`, `xterm`, etc., while using other programs, supposing that those other programs are identical to `dtterm`, `xterm`).

Here's a screenshot for instance from Oracle's documentation:

[image]

Given *that*, it is unclear what actual terminal was being used.

@jeff-schaller noticed the position of the scrollbar in the second screenshot and guessed that OP was expecting the terminal to skip down to the bottom of the scrolling area when typing into it.  That is a feature of `xterm` and [`rxvt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rxvt) (and perhaps a few other terminals).  From [xterm's manual](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html), there are resource settings:

> **`scrollKey`** (class **`ScrollCond`**)
>   Specifies whether or not pressing a  key  should  automatically
>   cause  the  scrollbar  to  go  to  the  bottom of the scrolling
>   region.  This corresponds to xterm's private  mode  1011.   The
>   default is "false".
>
> **`scrollTtyOutput`** (class **`ScrollCond`**)
>   Specifies whether or not output to the terminal should automatically cause the scrollbar to go to the bottom of the scrolling
>   region.  The default is "true".

as well as corresponding menu entries.  The [`dtterm` manual](http://cdesktopenv.sourceforge.net/man1/dtterm.html) does not mention a similar feature.

On the other hand, the `reset` command will not by itself force the terminal to scroll to the bottom (except as a side-effect, e.g., from `scrollTtyOutput`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my terminal, `dtterm`. Switching to `xterm` when using vim fixed it.